# What is an efficient workaround for using this inside anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

Main concern is efficiency.

I am working on javascript scopes and one thing that I am confused about is `this` inside a function.

I have read many answers and I understand them. But what I am concerned about is efficiency. Have a look at my code.

```
  class Fancy {
    constructor () {
  }

  checkScope (callback) {
    console.log('Inside checkScope');
    callback ();
  }
}

class Prog {
  constructor () {
    this.name = 'myProg';
    this.fancy = new Fancy ();
  }

  run () {
    var that = this;
    this.fancy.checkScope(function () {
      console.log('Name ', that.name);
    });
  }
}

var prog = new Prog ();
prog.run();
```

Now in `run()` I am storing reference of `this` in a local variable `that`. This is working for me. But is it safe? Is it efficient? If no, please suggest me a good strategy/trick.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is safe, but you can use the new [**arrow syntax**](https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/).It preserve the `this`.

```js
 class Fancy {
    constructor () {
  }

  checkScope (callback) {
    console.log('Inside checkScope');
    callback ();
  }
}

class Prog {
  constructor () {
    this.name = 'myProg';
    this.fancy = new Fancy ();
  }

  run () {
    // Here your don't need var that = this, 
    // because the arrow function gets the same this
    this.fancy.checkScope( () => {
      console.log('Name ', this.name);
    });
  }
}

var prog = new Prog ();
prog.run();
```

Every simple function has it's `this`, in your case your

```
 function () {
      console.log('Name ', this.name); // this is undefined in 'strict mode'
    }
```

has its own `this`.So you need to keep the `this` outside the function and use with alias in the function.In `ES6` there is a new `arrow syntax function`.`Arrow functions` don't override the `this`. In your case

```
run () {

        this.fancy.checkScope( () => {
          console.log('Name ', this.name);
        });
      }
```

the `this` in the `run function` and in the `parameter function` are the same. It means that in the `arrow function scope` the `this`  refers to that `this` in which the `arrow function` was defined.

In the case of efficient, you don't need an extra variable.You don't pollute the local scope with an extra variable. In the performance there is no affect.

Comment: Can you please explain how it going to help? And how it is difference.

Comment: @ZulfiqarJunejo see the updated version

Comment: @SurenSrapyan: That's fine, but I think the OP is interested about the "is it efficient?" part. So the question is whether this is more or less efficient than using the regular function scope by casting the "this" to another variable. -- +1 after edit ;D

Comment: I like @SurenSrapyan's answer. Thanks. I am accepting the answer.